# Convert grails app to plugin

Tags: grails, plugins

I started a grails application by grails create-app. For modularity, I feel like it would be better that component be a plugin. Can I convert this application into a grails plugin?
thanks,
Babu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never created a plugin based on an application written before but looking at the [documentation for grails plugins](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/12.%20Plug-ins.html) you can read the following statement:

> The structure of a Grails plugin is exactly the same as a regular Grails project's directory structure, except that in the root of the plugin directory you will find a plugin Groovy file called the "plugin descriptor".

So I would suggest to create a new plugin with `grails create-plugin *your-plugin-name*` and copy all files from your application into the plugin.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I'll try it out.. I am also trying to do a test plugin to see how they differ.. I'll conclude this thread if no one experienced with similar requirement comments. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is looking, this should be exactly what you need: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1973

Excerpt:

> So to convert an application to a plugin, the general workflow would
>   be something like
>
> - Create the plugin descriptor, FooGrailsPlugin.groovy. The easiest way to do this is to rungrails create-plugin pluginname and copy the
>     generated file from there
> - delete everything from application.properties except the app.grails.version property
> - if you have jars in the lib directory that are available in a Maven repo, delete them and replace with BuildConfig.groovy dependencies
> - change any plugin and jar dependencies that are needed for development and testing but not when the plugin is installed to not be
>     exported, by adding export = false
> - If you need the _Install.groovy, _Uninstall.groovy, or _Upgrade.groovy scripts (you probably don’t) grab those from the dummy plugin from step 1 (but delete any you don’t need, they’re all
>     optional)
> - delete ApplicationResources.groovy if you aren’t using it and don’t depend on resources plugin
> - move code from BootStrap.groovy init() toFooGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext
>     and/orFooGrailsPlugin.doWithDynamicMethods and destroy() to
>     FooGrailsPlugin.onShutdown, and delete BootStrap.groovy
> - add a dependency for the release plugin in BuildConfig.groovy
> - delete everything but the log4j configuration from Config.groovy
> - delete UrlMappings.groovy unless you have exported mappings; only keep the added ones
> - move bean definitions from resources.groovy to FooGrailsPlugin.doWithSpring and delete resources.groovy
> - delete grails-app/i18n message bundle files unless you added messages; only keep the added ones
> - delete everything from grails-app/views that you don’t use (in particular error.gsp,index.gsp, and layouts/main.gsp)
> - delete everything from web-app that you don’t use (including WEB-INF xml and tld files)
> - now would be a great time to write those tests you’ve been meaning to get to
> - create one or more test applications to install the plugin into to ensure that it works as a plugin; consider scripting this
> - write documentation for how to use the plugin; at a minimum a README file, but Grails gdoc files  would be much better (run grails doc
>     --init to get started)