# grails services :: multiple projects

Tags: grails, service, rabbitmq, zeromq

> PROBLEM :

I have multiple grails projects (lets say appA, appB and appC) : services to be precise

I want to run them in a single grails-app.. probably a war deployment, how can i do this?

> REQUIREMENTS :

I want this to be a single app since i am deploying it on cloud and i don't have enough memory to hold all these service instances individually.

The reason for multiple grails project is scalability. So that if later on i want to run 10 instance of appA, 3 instance of appB, and 1 instance of aapC; i should be able to do that.

EDIT :
Can i use something like 0mq, will that be helpful in keeping the services separated from each other. How will i package my service? And reading the docs of 0mq seems that it can work with both inprocess and external process.
Will async grails requests on HTTP work with 0mq in process/ external mq calls.
Haven't used 0mq, but from the initial doc it seems to work.  Need some experience calls in this scenario.

Are there any other alternatives or mq alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the services already decoupled, you should just make them into plugins.

A [grails plugin is much like a regular grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581088/convert-grails-app-to-plugin), it can add Domain Classes, Controllers, Services, etc, so you probably won't have much work turning your current applications into plugins. You'll mostly have to twiddle with the configuration a bit.

Then, you can create one big application including the three plugins, and whenever you want to deploy them as separated applications later, you can create three separate applications, one including each plugin.

Check out [the docs on Grails plugins](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build large webapp, you can utilize the [DataSources Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/datasources) to manage you separate connections within the same app. The problem that you'll run into is that if you lose access to any of your datasources the whole project will fail until it can make it's jdbc connections.